# CRC_CCITT Kermit 16 in C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a hard way that requires the CRC_CCITT Kermit 16 protocol with the formula (X16 + X12 + X5 + 1). However some of the code I've found online both on this site or the web in general I don't seem to get my desired result. I saw this website (http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html) that actually provides me with the exact match I want but it was written in C++. So can anyone help me with this?

I look forward to hearing from you.

Kind regards

Michael

Answer (score 4):

if you need CRC CCITT 16 Kermit you'll need the following code (from my site):

```
var crc16Kermit = new Crc16( Crc16Mode.CcittKermit );
var checksum = crc16Kermit.ComputeChecksumBytes( 0x01, 0x23, 0x45 );
// checksum = 0x2e, 0x46
```

here's the source for the above code

```
using System;

public enum Crc16Mode : ushort { Standard = 0xA001, CcittKermit = 0x8408 }

public class Crc16 {
    static ushort[] table = new ushort[256];

    public ushort ComputeChecksum( params byte[] bytes ) {
        ushort crc = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i) {
            byte index = (byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]);
            crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ table[index]);
        }
        return crc;
    }

    public byte[] ComputeChecksumBytes( params byte[] bytes ) {
        ushort crc = ComputeChecksum( bytes );
        return BitConverter.GetBytes( crc );
    }

    public Crc16( Crc16Mode mode ) {
        ushort polynomial = (ushort)mode;
        ushort value;
        ushort temp;
        for(ushort i = 0; i < table.Length; ++i) {
            value = 0;
            temp = i;
            for(byte j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
                if(((value ^ temp) & 0x0001) != 0) {
                    value = (ushort)((value >> 1) ^ polynomial);
                }else {
                    value >>= 1;
                }
                temp >>= 1;
            }
            table[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

link for the above code: http://sanity-free.org/147/standard_crc16_and_crc16_kermit_implementation_in_csharp.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want CRC16 CCITT. Try this:

```
using System;

public enum InitialCrcValue { Zeros, NonZero1 = 0xffff, NonZero2 = 0x1D0F }

public class Crc16Ccitt {
    const ushort poly = 4129;
    ushort[] table = new ushort[256];
    ushort initialValue = 0;

    public ushort ComputeChecksum(byte[] bytes) {
        ushort crc = this.initialValue;
        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i) {
            crc = (ushort)((crc << 8) ^ table[((crc >> 8) ^ (0xff & bytes[i]))]);
        }
        return crc;
    }

    public byte[] ComputeChecksumBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        ushort crc = ComputeChecksum(bytes);
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(crc);
    }

    public Crc16Ccitt(InitialCrcValue initialValue) {
        this.initialValue = (ushort)initialValue;
        ushort temp, a;
        for(int i = 0; i < table.Length; ++i) {
            temp = 0;
            a = (ushort)(i << 8);
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
                if(((temp ^ a) & 0x8000) != 0) {
                    temp = (ushort)((temp << 1) ^ poly);
                } else {
                    temp <<= 1;
                }
                a <<= 1;
            }
            table[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Source:
http://sanity-free.org/133/crc_16_ccitt_in_csharp.html

Comment: Apologies for my first answer, I clicked the wrong URL and ended up giving you code for plain CRC.